# Scaling With The App.js File When Using Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

So I was wondering. When a Vuejs app grows, thus the App.js file grows.
My question is:
How should and can this file be split up so each section of the site uses its own app.js file?

Comment: Can you tell me more about how you write your Vue app? Do you also use webpack or anything similar? Or you're just importing your application using `<script>` tags in HTML files? Have you heard of Vue's single file components before??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create separate functions or classes then import them to the App.js via `import` or using Require.js, Common.js etc. And the just call them inside the App.js

Comment: Aaahh Thank you. ok then just import the other app.js files into the main js file?
So say I have an app.js file and another file called abc.js,

In the app.js file I would simply add ```import Abc from './Abc.js';```

?

Answer (score 0):

If you find yourself wanting separate Vue instances / more than one Single Page App, you can try this [webpack template](https://github.com/Plortinus/vue-multiple-pages).